# TSQL Running Total

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am running MS SQL Server 2012. I'm trying to calculate a running total to date by month and cost type to trending. This query gives me the current months total correctly by cost types:

```
SELECT 
JCCD.Job
,JCCD.CostType
,JCCT.Description
,[Total] = SUM(JCCD.ProjCost) - SUM(JCCD.ActualCost)
FROM
JCCD JCCD
JOIN
JCCT JCCT
ON
JCCD.PhaseGroup = JCCT.PhaseGroup AND JCCD.CostType = JCCT.CostType
WHERE 
JCCo = 1 AND Job = 1378 AND JCCD.Mth <= '7/1/2019'
GROUP BY
JCCD.Job
,JCCD.CostType
,JCCT.Description
ORDER BY CostType
```

Correct Result:

```
Job CostType    Description Total
 1378.  1   Subcontractors  16145427.78
 1378.  3   Materials/Supplies  11338262.26
 1378.  4   Direct Labor (PR Use Only)  7132036.05
 1378.  5   Repairs 166219.65
 1378.  6   Fuel    976015.51
 1378.  7   Equipment   5309309.12
 1378.  9   Other Direct Costs  1994790.36
 1378.  90  Contingency 1859419.04
 1378.  95  Management Reserve  0.00
 1378.  100 Allocated Indirects 427724.92
```

But I'm failing at a cumulative running total per month by costtype. I can't quite seem to get figure out the partition function to get the cumulative per month by costtype. Here is one version of what I've tried which isn't correct:

```
SELECT
JCCD.Job
,JCCD.CostType
,Mth
,[Total] = SUM(JCCD.ProjCost) - SUM(JCCD.ActualCost)
,[RT] = SUM(JCCD.ProjCost) - SUM(JCCD.ActualCost) OVER (PARTITION BY Mth, CostType ORDER BY Mth, CostType RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM
JCCD JCCD
WHERE 
JCCo = 1 AND Job = ' 1378.' AND JCCD.Mth <= '7/1/2019'
GROUP BY
JCCD.Job
,JCCD.CostType
,ActualCost
,ProjCost
,Mth
ORDER BY Mth
```

Snippet of Result:

```
Job CostType    Mth Total   RT
 1378.  9   2019-07-01 00:00:00 -4207.50    -99105.59
 1378.  9   2019-07-01 00:00:00 -5036.61    -99105.59
 1378.  9   2019-07-01 00:00:00 -5880.19    -99105.59
 1378.      9   2019-07-01 00:00:00 -7788.37    -99105.59
 1378.  9   2019-07-01 00:00:00 -35778.60   -99105.59
 1378.  9   2019-07-01 00:00:00 -29694.75   -99105.59
 1378.  100 2019-07-01 00:00:00 -35079.22   -17539.61
```

Help! :-)

I tried the suggestion below, but that didn't quite provide the results I was interested in, here is a snippet of those results. If I had a sum per month by cost type, that would be correct.

```
Job CostType    Mth Total   RT  RT2
 1378.      9   2019-05-01 00:00:00 -191.99 2302027.86  42364678.68
 1378.      9   2019-05-01 00:00:00 -628.76 2302027.86  42364678.68
 1378.      9   2019-05-01 00:00:00 -681.00 2302027.86  42364678.68
 1378.      9   2019-05-01 00:00:00 -1481.18    2302027.86  42364678.68
 1378.      9   2019-05-01 00:00:00 -765.06 2302027.86  42364678.68
 1378.  9   2019-05-01 00:00:00 -944.25 2302027.86  42364678.68
 1378.      9   2019-05-01 00:00:00 -1068.50    2302027.86  42364678.68
 1378.      9   2019-05-01 00:00:00 -1082.00    2302027.86  42364678.68
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would work, you may have to change `PARTITION BY` columns that fits your need.

```
select   T.*
        ,[RT] = SUM(t.[Total]) OVER (PARTITION BY Mth, CostType ORDER BY Mth, CostType RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
        ,[RT2] = SUM(t.[Total]) OVER (PARTITION BY Mth ORDER BY CostType)
from    (  SELECT   JCCD.Job
                    ,JCCD.CostType
                    ,Mth
                    ,[Total] = SUM(JCCD.ProjCost) - SUM(JCCD.ActualCost)
            FROM JCCD JCCD
            WHERE JCCo = 1 AND Job = ' 1378.' AND JCCD.Mth <= '7/1/2019'
            GROUP BY JCCD.Job, JCCD.CostType, ActualCost, ProjCost,Mth
        ) as T
ORDER BY Mth
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I tried it out but unfortunately it doesn't have the intended effect I was hoping for.

Comment: Could you please prepare script that can populate sample data as per your current table and data structure, so that it would be easy to work for solution and we all in same page.